# android app stopped unfortunately

Tags: android-geofence

When I run the app in emulator it says app stopped unfortunately.
Here is the logcat, can anyone find what is the error?

> 08-29 12:57:01.014: E/Trace(780): error opening trace file: No such
>   file or directory (2) 08-29 12:57:01.244: D/AndroidRuntime(780):
>   Shutting down VM 08-29 12:57:01.244: W/dalvikvm(780): threadid=1:
>   thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930) 08-29
>   12:57:01.334: E/AndroidRuntime(780): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 08-29
>   12:57:01.334: E/AndroidRuntime(780): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.android.geofence/com.example.android.geofence.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.example.android.geofence.MainActivity" on path:
>   /data/app/com.example.android.geofence-2.apk 08-29 12:57:01.334:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(780):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
>   08-29 12:57:01.334: E/AndroidRuntime(780):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>   08-29 12:57:01.334: E/AndroidRuntime(780):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 08-29
>   12:57:01.334: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>   08-29 12:57:01.334: E/AndroidRuntime(780):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 08-29
>   12:57:01.334: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 08-29 12:57:01.334:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(780):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 08-29
>   12:57:01.334: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 08-29
>   12:57:01.334: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 08-29 12:57:01.334:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(780):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   08-29 12:57:01.334: E/AndroidRuntime(780):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 08-29
>   12:57:01.334: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 08-29 12:57:01.334:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(780): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   Didn't find class "com.example.android.geofence.MainActivity" on path:
>   /data/app/com.example.android.geofence-2.apk 08-29 12:57:01.334:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(780):    at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
>   08-29 12:57:01.334: E/AndroidRuntime(780):    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501) 08-29
>   12:57:01.334: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461) 08-29
>   12:57:01.334: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
>   08-29 12:57:01.334: E/AndroidRuntime(780):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
>   08-29 12:57:01.334: E/AndroidRuntime(780):    ... 11 more

Answer (score 0):

This is the exception:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.geofence.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.android.geofence-2.a`pk

Try cleaning and building your project and run it again on emulator.

Answer (score 0):

The interesting part is here

```
12:57:01.334: E/AndroidRuntime(780): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.geofence.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.android.geofence-2.apk
```

Please check if your main activity is really called `com.example.android.geofence.MainActivity`